# Disable Soft Keyboard on Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, android-softkeyboard

I need to disable the soft keyboard on xamarin forms for custom entry. Ive searched for some solutions, tried some suggestions i found, but the keyboard still shows when customentry gets focus. If i tap on the control, keyboard doesnt showing, but if i make .Focus() in code, it appears. Heres some code i have, and what i tried to do:
in XAML:

```
<cutom:tb1 x:Name="tb1" Grid.Column="2"/>
```

then the customentry:

```
public class tb1 : Entry
{
}
```

the android custom renderer, with the codes i tried:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(tb1), typeof(tb1Renderer))]
```

namespace whatever.Droid
{
class tb1Renderer : EntryRenderer
{
public tb1Renderer(Context context) : base(context)
{
}

```
    public override bool OnCheckIsTextEditor()
    {
        return false;
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.Null;
        }

        // Disable the Keyboard on Focus
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            ((tb1)e.NewElement).PropertyChanging += DisableKeyboard;
        }

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            ((tb1)e.OldElement).PropertyChanging -= DisableKeyboard;
        }

        this.Control.ShowSoftInputOnFocus = false;
        if ((e.OldElement == null) && (Control != null))
        {
            HideKeyboard();
        }
    }

    private void DisableKeyboard(object sender, PropertyChangingEventArgs propertyChangingEventArgs)
    {
        // Check if the view is about to get Focus
        if (propertyChangingEventArgs.PropertyName == VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            // incase if the focus was moved from another Entry
            // Forcefully dismiss the Keyboard 
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
            imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(this.Control.WindowToken, 0);
        }
    }

    public void HideKeyboard()
    {
        Control.RequestFocus();
        var inputMethodManager = Control.Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService) as InputMethodManager;
        inputMethodManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow(this.Control.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
    }

}
```

}

tryed to turn that off in MainActivity.cs aswell

```
[Activity(WindowSoftInputMode = Android.Views.SoftInput.StateAlwaysHidden, ...
```

again, the keyboard does not show if i tap on entry, but when i make a button and a click event, the keyboard still shows

```
private async void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try { //await work to do }
        catch(Exception ex) { //some logging }
        finally { tb1.Focus(); }
    }
```

Comment: If there isn't supposed to be any keyboard, why are you using an `Entry`? Just show text in a `Label`. Then whatever user does (that isn't a soft keyboard), write code that makes the appropriate change to label's text. Or explain in more detail what the situation is, such that you want an Entry but no soft keyboard. Worst case, google how to create a custom keyboard, then create one with zero height and no keys on it.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve i need Entry for capturing data from USB scanner.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that explanation does not make any sense to me. "USB scanner data" seems unrelated to whether you display text in an Entry or a Label. It would be helpful to **add your code to the question**, to show how that Entry is involved in "capturing data from USB scanner". Also, **show any code that alters the contents of that Entry.** Then, attempt to change it from `<Entry ...>` to `<Label ...>`, and report exactly what goes wrong.

Comment: If there is some example code you are following, also add a link to that example page.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve what USB scanner does is just emulating keypress, so i dont have code for that. So if i want to get the data from scanner, app must have focus on some imput field, which is entry.

Comment: I suspect that Android OS, when each key appears from USB scanner, shows the keyboard again. Either add to [Edit Text's Keypress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/edit-text) logic to hide keyboard again, or make a custom soft keyboard that is empty and has zero height (or a small height).

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation, I conclude that code we don't have access to brings up the soft keyboard under some circumstances. AFTER IsFocused, so hiding it at that time is not sufficient.

If you need an Entry to have focus, but no soft keyboard,
the best solution I found, is to let it appear, then **after a brief delay**, tell it to go away.

```
/// <summary>
/// When IsFocused is becoming true, Hide soft keyboard after a slight delay.
/// </summary>
private void DisableKeyboard(object sender, PropertyChangingEventArgs propertyChangingEventArgs)
{
    // Check if the view is gaining Focus.
    if (propertyChangingEventArgs.PropertyName == VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty.PropertyName) {
        if (this.HasFocus) {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
                // TBD whether this needs to be longer (100?) on some devices.
                await Task.Delay(1);
                Android.Util.Log.Warn("-----", "HideSoftInputFromWindow -----");
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
                imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(this.Control.WindowToken, 0);
            });
        }
    }
}

// Might or might not find this useful.
protected override void OnFocusChangeRequested(object sender, VisualElement.FocusRequestArgs e)
{
    Android.Util.Log.Warn("-----", $"OnFocusChangeRequested f={e.Focus}, r={e.Result} -----");
    // Change the default behavior. This seems to suppress (or defer?) IsFocused event in some circumstances. Making the above code more useful.
    // Test what happens if user touches the Entry; this should help.
    if (e.Focus)
        e.Result = !e.Result;
}
```

Comment: Still, the keyboard shows, after it gets hidden...I need stop keyboard before it shows.

Comment: @Taliga - If it still shows, make a custom keyboard that is empty and has zero height (or a very small height). Follow any instructions for making a custom keyboard.

Comment: yes, probably a custom keyboard will be the solution for now....its sad tough that a so simle thing like this is so annoyingly complicated to solve...

Answer (score 1):

I found a good solution which works for editor and entry elements.

I'll show it for Entry.

First you have to create a custom class which inherits from entry:

```
public class NoKeyboardEntry : Entry
{
}
```

Afterwards you have to create a custom renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NoKeyboardEntry), typeof(NoKeyboardEntryRenderer))]
namespace Projekt.Droid
{
    public class NoKeyboardEntryRenderer: EntryRenderer
    {

        public NoKeyboardEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnFocusChangeRequested(object sender, VisualElement.FocusRequestArgs e)
        {
            e.Result = true;

            if (e.Focus)
                this.Control.RequestFocus();
            else
                this.Control.ClearFocus();

            // Disable the Keyboard on Focus
            Control.ShowSoftInputOnFocus = false;
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                ((NoKeyboardEntry)e.NewElement).PropertyChanging += OnPropertyChanging;
            }

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                ((NoKeyboardEntry)e.OldElement).PropertyChanging -= OnPropertyChanging;
            }
            // Disable the Keyboard on Focus
            Control.ShowSoftInputOnFocus = false;
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanging(object sender, PropertyChangingEventArgs propertyChangingEventArgs)
        {
            // Check if the view is about to get Focus
            if (propertyChangingEventArgs.PropertyName == VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Disable the Keyboard on Focus
                    Control.ShowSoftInputOnFocus = false;

                    // incase if the focus was moved from another Entry
                    // Forcefully dismiss the Keyboard 
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
                    imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(Control.WindowToken, 0);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _ = ex;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add Focus and Tapped Event in OnElementChanged method to disable the keyboard by the Handler.Post such as

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.Click += (sender, evt) => {
                new Handler().Post(delegate
                {
                    var imm = (InputMethodManager)Control.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.InputMethodService);
                    var result = imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(Control.WindowToken, 0);
                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                });
            };
            Control.FocusChange += (sender, evt) => {
                new Handler().Post(delegate
                {
                    var imm = (InputMethodManager)Control.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.InputMethodService);
                    var result = imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(Control.WindowToken, 0);

                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                });
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code, it hides the keyboard... the problem is, the keyboard still pops up, after it is showed, it gets hidden. I need a way to stop keyboart before it starts showing up.

Comment: This is a good answer. Unfortunately, this won't solve the problem in OP's situation. The keyboard is not appearing due to user action - it is appearing because something deep inside the system believes it should make sure the keyboard is showing when the USB scanner sends keys to the focused control. It does "Show" again - no way to stop it, as far as I could determine. This happens AFTER the events intercepted in this answer.

Comment: Ah, I know. Can you add to your answer a handler of [EditText - KeyPress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/edit-text), to hide it again. Sounds like Android OS makes it show again.

Comment: The Entry.Focus method make the soft keyboard show. So If you want the keyboard never appear, you have to override the Focus method or custom a Entry and custom the Focus method to make the soft keyboard never appear. But we can't override the Entry.Focus in Xamarin, we can just custom an Entry.